# Environment variable returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's how I set my ENV variable

```
#~/repos/project
export GA_USERNAME="email@gmail.com"
```

When I try to use `ENV['GA_USERNAME]` in my application, it returns nil. However, in the console it strangely prints the variable and then returns nil...

```
1.9.2-p320 :003 > puts ENV['GA_USERNAME']
email@gmail.com
=> nil
```

**Edit** I don't think my ENV variables are persisting. When I restart my computer, variable is nil and needs to be set again.

Comment: `puts` always returns `nil`... try just `ENV['GA_USERNAME']`

Comment: interesting. yes that worked in the console, but it is still returning nil when I run the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional way to set env vars for a server process is:

```
RAILS_ENV=production GA_USERNAME=foobar rails s
```

If you want to specify the env vars in a persistent way, like in a file, try [`figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). The README tells you how to start, but the idea is:

1. `rails generate figaro:install`
2. edit `config/application.yml` (which the last command created)
3. in your app, it will automatically set per-environment (production, development, test) variables

**UPDATE**

[`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) might be an even better and simpler approach:

1. `gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]`
2. put cross-environment key-value pairs in `.env`
3. put env-specific pairs `.env.test` or `.env.development`

See their README for all the details.

Comment: Do I `export` this? I'm trying to set the development env.